# How to dump postgres database and sync with other postgres database using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, cron

I have 2 database servers. One for dev and one for production, what I want to do is to create a dumb of production DB and sync it with dev DB at a specific time using nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres provides pg_dump (single DB) and pg_dumpall (all DBs) utilities out of the box. The simplest way would probably be a cron job to automate the backup of your source DB and scp it over to a destination server, then restore the DB on the destination server by a cron job:

On the source server:

```
crontab -e
0 0 * * 0 pg_dumpall -U postgres > ~/backups/backup.bak
# scp to your destination server
```

If you’re working in one of the major cloud environments they will have their own tools that can help, eg AWS you can automate snapshots, then restore from a snapshot (or have a lambda perform the restore from the snapshot as you suggest in nodeJs)

Or (super-cool way) is to use AWS DMS (Data Migration Services) CDC - Change Data Capture and you can replicate a source DB instantaneously with one or many target replicas (avoiding the need for dumps and restores)

Answer (score 0):

I asume you meant dump, and googled that for you:
https://www.joseverissimo.com/blog/automatically-export-a-database-and-import-it-to-another-using-node-js

Now you just should make sure it runs as a cronjob.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).